# Master-Slave replication is not working but status is ok

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, replication, master-slave

Did replication on the tutorial. **SHOW SLAVE STATUS** shows that everything is ok.

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes,
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes,
Last_Errno: 0,
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
```

No errors will not fall, with any changes on the master, the position and file on the slave are identical to the master.

BUT the problem is that no changes occur in the slave database.  **Seconds_Behind_Master: 0** and there are still no errors. Logs mariadb empty, respectively, requests to the database simply do not reach.

Can anyone come across such a problem? What can you think of?

Comment: I think you want [ru.so]

Comment: Sounds like `log_bin` is not on, or something else in the Master is preventing replication.  Shows the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
This happens when I create Master-Slave replication in two CentOS servers. 
In Ubuntu with this configuration everything is okay.